# Tiny Modification to Near Perfect Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Earlier today I was able to find a slider that I modified to meet my needs for a webdesign project I was working on.

I had one simple issue with this slider though, I was not able to modify the script to center the images when they slide so that the main image appears in the middle of the screen, before the slide and after sliding (either to the left or right).

Here is the JSFiddle (excuse me if I'm doing it wrong this is my first time using it): http://jsfiddle.net/6CfbC/

Any advice with that would help a lot, and if possible is there anyway where I can make it loop? to where there part of the last slide shows to the left of the first slide and when I slide all the way to the end of either side it loops?

Thank You In Advance Guys.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it looks right after I corrected the HTML.

Your `<li>` elements were missing the beginning `<` in a lot of places:

```
>li>
```

Here is an updated fiddle that seems fine to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/6CfbC/1/

Comment: I didn't realize that but as soon as I made  those edits nothing really changed. here is what I see while scrolling and that is also where the first slide begins: http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/1280/46755413.jpg (highlighted in red)

Comment: @user1232698: Can you provide the updated code?  Your old code starts making the images bigger towards the end and doesn't align with the defined width/height, but my edited fiddle stops doing that and everything looks right.

Comment: Also I looked at the elastislide code re your 2nd question (should be a separate question on SO), and I can't find a simple way to do it with the predefined interface.  You could probably edit the source code to do it, tho.  Try this: Change the implementation of `_slide`, after the animation check, to figure out if `current` is the last one/first one (depending on direction).  If so, set current to the wrapped-around value, and call `_slideToCurrent`

Comment: the corrected code with a few css adjustments: http://jsfiddle.net/szBMx/1/

if you have a bigger screen you can see that the main slide (usually the slide in between the other two) is not centered on the page... I'd like to be able to center it on the page.

Comment: I'll definitely look into it, my limited knowledge of javascript makes it a bit more difficult to learn jquery but I have began doing so.

Answer (score 0):

i think you would better go with scrollable - wich has a looping plugin called circular: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/index.html

<strike>these half starting slides are mostly mistakes in the animate functions or css mistakes at your wrapper arround the slider (is it wide enough for all of your slides? (yes it is!))</strike>

your broken html

```
</li>li>
```

did it as mentioned by others

but its weird to duplicate all slides 4 times and still dont loop....

Comment: I Might have a go with the scrollables but I am almost done with this one so I'm going to try to battle it out... check my comment above, it honestly hasn't fixed my issue.